# White screen after running my flutter web application

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have searched and tried a lot of methods.
One works for me is this command `flutter run -d chrome --release`.
What a pity that no debug info print out.

When i run it directly by pressing button in Android studio, my website showed nothing but white screen.
I got follow message from the Console

> Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
> Syncing files to device Chrome...

I want to run it and get debug info. Who has good ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem finally be solved, Firstly, Press F12 when you deploy your web to your Chrome browser. Then all debug info will be printed in Chrome Console.  My problem is caused by

```
   require.js:1959 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/project/flutter_afast/lib/model/builder.dart
   req.load @ require.js:1959
```

Which caused by a import of absolute path(local path E:/...) in my dart file. Change this to relative path then work that problem out.